# Spark 2.3 (Scala) - Convert a timestamp column from UTC to timezone specified in another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a data frame with data like this:

```
    +----------------------+------------+
    | utc_timestamp        | tz_locale  |
    +----------------------+------------+
    |2021-07-16T10:00:00Z  | US/Eastern |
    |2021-07-19T15:00:00Z  | US/Central |
    +----------------------+------------+
```

I want to convert the timestamps from UTC (TZ 0) to the local time based on the value in the `tz_locale` column:

```
    +--------------------------+------------+
    | utc_timestamp            | tz_locale  |
    +--------------------------+------------+
    |2021-07-16T06:00:00-04:00 | US/Eastern |
    |2020-12-19T09:00:00-06:00 | US/Central |
    +--------------------------+------------+
```

I tried writing it like this:

```
val new_df = df.withColumn("utc_timestamp", from_utc_timestamp(df.col("utc_timestamp"), df.col("tz_locale")))
```

It appears `from_utc_timestamp` wants a String constant for the second argument, so it apparently only works to convert the entire column to the same timezone. But I need to convert each row dynamically based on the value of another column in that row.

I think this is possible in newer versions of Spark (`from_utc_timestamp` is overloaded with a version that takes `(DataFrame.col, DataFrame.col)`), but I am on 2.3 and upgrading is not an option. How can this be done in Spark 2.3? It seems like a fairly common task but I can't figure it out, and couldn't find anything using search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Spark 2.3 or older, you can take advantage of using the less type-constrained SQL expression via `expr`:

```
df.withColumn("utc_timestamp", expr("from_utc_timestamp(utc_timestamp, tz_locale)")).show

+-------------------+----------+
|      utc_timestamp| tz_locale|
+-------------------+----------+
|2021-07-15 23:00:00|US/Eastern|
|2021-07-19 03:00:00|US/Central|
+-------------------+----------+
```